# OpenLDAP after initial install TLS enabled, how to start?

Tags: ssl, openldap

After yum installing openldap on rhel7 I try to start slapd, and it gives a TLS error.

```
main: TLS init def ctx failed: -1
```

Because of config :

```
olcTLSCACertificatePath: /etc/openldap/certs
olcTLSCertificateFile: "OpenLDAP Server"
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/password
```

So, I need to change that. But the file says :

```
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
```

So, to run ldapmodify I need to start slapd. Which I can't do because the config is wrong.
I even tried creating a crt and key and putting them in that folder with those names.

```
ls -l certs/
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 ldap ldap 1172 Nov  2 10:19 OpenLDAP Server
-rw------- 1 ldap ldap 1675 Nov  2 10:19 password
```

I'm aware that I could hack the config file and remove the TLS lines and recalculate the CRC, but surely that isn't what you're supposed to do. Is it? Kind of makes perl-Archive-Zip and the crc32 command a dependency of the openldap package...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the offending lines from the ldif file and then use `slapadd -b cn=config /path/to/modified/file.ldif` to load the modified file.

Comment: Nope. 
[root@ip-10-66-2-205 slapd.d]# slapadd -b cn=config /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config.ldif 


usage: slapadd [-v] [-d debuglevel] [-f configfile] [-F configdir] [-o <name>[=<value>]] [-c]
 [-g] [-n databasenumber | -b suffix]
 [-l ldiffile] [-j linenumber] [-q] [-u] [-s] [-w]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this was restricted to AWS Linux2. On RHEL7 it isn't a problem but I hadn't spotted which OS I was on.

AWS support suggests initialising the certs DB with :

```
$ sudo /usr/libexec/openldap/create-certdb.sh
$ sudo /usr/libexec/openldap/generate-server-cert.sh
```